# UWP-VB Error message popup using MessageDialog

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, popup, win-universal-app, messagebox

I'm pretty new at UWP so it's hard time for me. I'm creating some basic caluclator for start to see what I can eat this thing with. I came across some little probelm which is error handling with pop-ups.

```
        On Error Resume Next
    Dim check2 As Double
    check2 = YA_txt.Text * 1
    If Error.Number = 0 Then GoTo XA
    If Error.Number > 0 Then GoTo error2
error2:
        If Error.Number = 13 Then
            MsgBox("Wrong coordinates", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End If
```

But now I don't have MsgBox and there is MessageDialog but it's async and this cannot be used with Error and Resume... how can I handle it?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use try catch instead of on error, and you will display message depending on the type of error.

```
Try
    Dim check2 As Double
    check2 = TextBox1.Text * 1
Catch ex As ArithmeticException 'type exception
    Dim dialog = New MessageDialog("Wrong coordinates")
    dialog.Title = "Error"
    dialog.Commands.Add(New UICommand() With { Key.Label = "Ok", Key.Id = 0})
    dialog.Commands.Add(New UICommand() With { Key.Label = "Cancel", Key.Id = 1})
    Dim res = Await dialog.ShowAsync()
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    '...
'Catch ....

End Try
```

Comment: In UWA I don't have such thing as "MsgBox" it's underscored as Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30451 'MsgBox' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: I believe forgiveness is vba Ms Office, Because you make a vba tag in question

Comment: Yes it works. But I still don't see option with error handling. As I cannot use "On Error Resume Next"

Comment: you can use try catch instead of on error (view answer)